# Datetime picker doesn't work when we use jQuery steps on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, datetimepicker

I was trying to add a datetime picker jQuery steps and the datetime picker didn't respond properly.. and when I remove init of steps script it works fine...

[image: datetime picker]

Could I know the solution??

Here are the jQuery steps init script:

```js
var form = $("#profile_form").show();
form.steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "fieldset",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
        // Allways allow previous action even if the current form is not valid!
        if (currentIndex > newIndex) {
            return true;
        }
        // Forbid next action on "Warning" step if the user is to young
        if (newIndex === 3 && Number($("#age-2").val()) < 18) {
            return false;
        }
        // Needed in some cases if the user went back (clean up)
        if (currentIndex < newIndex) {
            // To remove error styles
            form.find(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") label.error").remove();
            form.find(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") .error").removeClass("error");
        }
        // form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
        return true;
    },
    onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, priorIndex) {
        // Used to skip the "Warning" step if the user is old enough.
        if (currentIndex === 2 && Number($("#age-2").val()) >= 18) {
            form.steps("next");
        }
        // Used to skip the "Warning" step if the user is old enough and wants to the previous step.
        if (currentIndex === 2 && priorIndex === 3) {
            form.steps("previous");
        }
    },
    onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex) {
        return true;
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
        alert("Submitted!");
    }
});
```

and here is my datetime picker init script:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
        widgetPositioning: {
            horizontal: 'auto',
            vertical: 'bottom'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What are you getting exactly in error/console or share any screenshot.

Comment: _"didn't respond properly"_ is not specific enough to even guess at an answer. How _**did**_ it behave? How did you _**expect**_ it to behave? Were there, as turivishal asks, any errors displayed in the console? Please read [ask] in the Help Center.

Comment: no there are no errors in console and no warnings.. its just the the picker is not visible properly as it should be.. in other pages without jquary steps it works properly.

Comment: please check the link i have attached..for image @StephenP